# Android AutoCompleteTextView can't exit input keyboard

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Hello fellow Android programmers,

today I wanted to create a simple AutoCompleteTextView with a custom Adapter, which works perfectly fine on the Emulator. But if I now run the whole thing on my Samsung Galaxy Young and I enter some text into the ACTextView, it suggests me everything as it should, but I can't click the "OK" button in the bottom right corner of the keyboard that is showing up.

If I flip the Smartphone and change orientation, I get rid of the annoying keyboard, but I can't close it any other way. Solutions? Here is the code and xml used:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/vereinAutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hint="@string/vereinHint"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions">
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

And the Java code for the Adapter (it's a custom one):

```
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.verein_layout, container, false);

        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.vereinAutoComplete);
        acTextView.setAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter(getActivity(),acTextView.getText().toString()));
        acTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
```

I am using the whole thing in a Fragment, so don't wonder the rootView and so on...
There is some code for the Listener, but I don't think it is important for my question.